# Transforming a string to a list of expressions

Tags: list-manipulation, import, string-manipulation

I have a string of the following form:

```
   myString= "{{Lambda[1], 0}, {2*Lambda[1] - 2*Lambda[2], 1}, {-4*Lambda[2], 2}, {-3*Lambda[1] + 2*Lambda[2], 1}, {-2*Lambda[1] - 3*Lambda[2], 3}, {-4*Lambda[1] + Lambda[2], 2}}"
```

So essentially it is almost a list.

I want to transform it into an actual list, such that strings pieces like `"-3*Lambda[1]"` are turned into actual expression `-3 Lambda[1]`, and the end result should be just a list.

```
{{Lambda[1], 0}, {2*Lambda[1] - 2*Lambda[2], 1}, {-4*Lambda[2], 2}, {-3*Lambda[1] + 2*Lambda[2], 1}, {-2*Lambda[1] - 3*Lambda[2], 3}, {-4*Lambda[1] + Lambda[2], 2}}
```

I wonder how to achieve this?

Comment: Try `ToExpression[myString]`

Comment: @Nasser works great. Thanks!

Comment: `Interpreter["Expression"][myString]`